# What research in theoretical physics could a high school student do?

Tags: soft-question, education

I already know what  I want to conduct my research on (topic: magnetic monopoles), the problem is just that I don't know what to investigate or analyze. What are some research methods you would recommend? What are some easily applicable concepts? Preferably, rather advanced topics/math, but "simple" execution.

To be clear, I am not interested in specific examples of what I can do, but rather a more general description of how I would be able to come up with something useful that I can use to conduct my research.

Comment: This question will likely be closed for being too opinion-based, but I'll comment on it. In my experience, very few **undergrads** do research when they are interested in theory. In fact, it might take even a couple of years of grad school before students actually start working in research, and very often (I'd say almost always) they start working in problems proposed by much more experienced researchers. It takes a lot of time, effort, and experience to be able to understand what problems are open in theoretical physics. I never heard of a single HS student doing research in theor. physics.

Comment: In order to research magnetic monopoles nowadays, you'll likely need to at least have a good grasp of [quantum field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory), which already has essentially everything in an undergrad curricullum as a prerequisite.

Comment: Doing research is a lot like doing challenging homework problems that you invent yourself instead of finding them in a book.  So a good way to start is by getting a few textbooks aimed at strong students, working end- of-chapter problems, and then thinking about how the solutions might have worked out differently if you'd changed some of the assumptions.   Try compiling a systematic account of how different assumptions lead to different conclusions.  You are, at that point, essentially doing research.

Comment: For more on opinion-based questions, see [this link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)

Comment: @NíckolasAlves I fully understand that it is a very difficult task and that it requires a lot of advanced knowledge in the topic, but I have seen it being done. It is highly probable that I won't succeed, but I would at least like to try. I'm not looking to revolutionize the specific area, it's more the fact that I am conducting my own research, even if it's not useful **at all**. Also, do you know other more fitting places or websites where I would be able to ask this question?

Comment: @TimHulland I *think* [Academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) might be suitable because I've seen opinion based questions there, but I'm not completely sure. I'm not aware of other websites (but feel free to hit me up on Twitter if you want, check my profile for info)

The best advice I can give you is to look for an advisor, which is someone (usually a professor or a post-doc) to guide you in your endeavors and help you out. It often takes at least five years to learn the bare minimum of what it is to do research, and we rely advisors to guide us by example

Comment: Also, it should be mentioned that it is **incredibly** easy for HS students to do something they consider research and is anything but that, or even to study Physics in a wrong way (there is no right way, but there are wrong ways). I've seen both cases with brilliant students who would have used their time much better had they had the proper guidance. I really recommend not trying to figure it out all by yourself. Search for an advisor or at least a mentor. Physics is collaborative, and trying to it alone without the proper experience frequently leads to regret

Comment: @NíckolasAlves Thank you for the advice!

Comment: All other answers are correct (finding a mentor and studying the field etc.), but if you really want to go it alone for now, the most productive avenue may be to develop your coding / simulation skills. Being able to code up a good simulation of your system of interest is a useful skill in most areas of physics, and something you can start to experiment with in relative isolation. In fact a quick google search shows a few open source codes for simulating magnetic monopoles which you could download and immediately start playing with.

Answer (score 2):

To do research is to go into territory that is either not-yet-entirely-charted, or at the most challenging end of the spectrum: uncharted territory.

The uncharted territory is at the *periphery* of the body of knowledge that the physics community has amassed. Over time students of physics have to cover more and more ground to eventually arrive at the periphery, where the available maps show mostly white areas.

However: there are also small whitish patches in nearby territory:

One example of a that, in my opinion, is the [Dzhanibekov effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_racket_theorem)

I recommend the following article by Nicholas Mecholsky:
[Analytic formula for the Geometric Phase of an Asymmetric Top](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03867)

And the following video by David Brown:
[The Dzhanibekov Effect: Equations and Simulations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1h4zlDRjV0c)

This is not a suggestion to you to take up those subjects, I'm mentioning this to show that nearby too there are still new insights to be had. Not necessarily new discovery, but new clarity, deeper understanding.

There are a lot of attempts out there to explain the Dzhanibekov effect, and there are noticable differences. That means that those people do not actually understand it as well as they think they understand it.

(Nicholas Mecholsky and David Brown do understand, which is why I recommend them.)

We now live in the age of internet connectivity; information is accessible at a level and speed that is far, far beyond any level ever in history.

I very much believe there are possibilities.
I believe there are opportunities for discovery nearby.

For sure, you will have to be very attentive. Look voor areas where explanations that are given are a bit fuzzy.

Possibly you will find an area where there is still some new understanding to be found.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you , I would search colleges and study for good grades in High School which would put me in a good college  instead of doing research on my own in physics.

But if you want to do research on your own I suggest before the research to study the basics about the subject of research.I would probably pick something which I have access to devices which can perform my experiment.

In order to search for magnetic monopoles you need a particle collider which isnt something regular people have access easily.